# Central align masonry grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, masonry

I am trying to do 2 things:

1. Make masonry grid 100% width and central align elements
2. Use bootstrap visibility classes to show/hide certain elements

I did the code like so:

```js
$('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  gutter: 5,
  fitWidth: true
});
```

```css
.grid-item{
  margin: 0 auto 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4.2.2/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x150" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x150" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid-item d-lg-block d-none"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x150" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

I am using `fitWidth: true` but the grid container is fixed width.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

the Masonry setting is **isFitWidth**: true,

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  gutter: 5, 
  isFitWidth: true,
});
```

[Masonry's Codepen example](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/nGLvx)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to center the entire .grid using the Bootstrap `mx-auto` class...

```
<div class="grid mx-auto">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item">...</div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/kHGkGI4s11